# How do I know who I shared my Outlook calendar with?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-office, microsoft-office-2007, exchange

I shared my calendar with some people and I need to know exactly who I shared it with. Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Right click on the calendar in question, click Properties and then Permissions. If you added someone as a Delegate, it is Tools, Options, Delgates

Comment: +1 Though I hope you can add some images to make it more visual

Comment: That was it, thanks! For those who are reading this later, you get to the "calendar in question" as DaveM put it by going into your navigation pane on the left, then under "My Calendars" (that is the default name), right-click on the calendar that has a checkbox by it (that is the one you are looking at). Then follow DaveM's directions.